# IOS XMPPFramework and Joining Rooms

Tags: objective-c, xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework

We are creating a chat application on IOS with using XMPPFramework on client side (https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework) and Ejabberd on server side.

In group chat, we are creating a group and after that join that group and invite other users to join our group. And everytime a new invited user joined to group , we inform all participants that the new user joined to group.

However when we restart the application (kill and relaunch), we store the username of that group and rejoin it again (you can find the example below), but in that case ejabberd send all clients that a new user joined to group but I was already in that group , only difference is I've relaunch the application.
How can I differantiate those 2 things?

```
NSString *nickName = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:userNickName];

XMPPRoomMemoryStorage *roomStorage = [[XMPPRoomMemoryStorage alloc] init];

XMPPJID *roomJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:uniqId];
XMPPRoom *xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc]initWithRoomStorage:roomStorage
                                                      jid:roomJID
                                            dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[xmppRoom activate:xmppStream];
[xmppRoom addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[xmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:nickName history:nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually joined in XMPP MUC means that you are now present in the room. When you are offline, you may be a member of the group, but you are not present in the group. When you send the presence again on login, then you are effectively present again.

I guess the root cause is that you are mixing join vs membership.

I suggest you have a look at MUC/Sub protocol in ejabberd. It was design to split presence in the room from room membership and subscription to messages.
The protocol is described here: https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/xmpp-clients-bots/proposed-extensions/muc-sub/

Answer (score 2):

In Xmpp MUC:

Leave != `Not group member anymore` or

Join  != `Become group member from now on`

But simply means:

Leave == `Presence unavailable` or

Join  == `Presence available`.

---

And Presence is not that useful in group chat.

In contrast, I think you are looking for something like `MUCLight`:

- https://xmpp.org/extensions/inbox/muc-light.html
- https://github.com/esl/MongooseIM/wiki/MUC-Light